# PHP 8 in Visual Studio Code

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, php-8, intelephense

I use the latest Version of Visual Studio Code (1.52.1) with PHP Intelephense 1.5.4 on Ubuntu. Despite it is the latest Version it seems not to know the new PHP 8 Syntax. For example it shows an error when using the nullsafe operator:

```
$myobject?->myfunction();
```

Is there a way to teach VSC PHP 8 or do we have to just wait for an update?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should point Visual Studio Code to the location of PHP interpreter that you want to use.

You can do it by setting a line in the `settings.json` like this:

```
"php.validate.executablePath": "c:/usr/php8.1/php.exe",
```

It is a VSCode configuration option but seems to work with Intelephense too.

You can also do it on per project basis using a separate `settings.json` file residing in project's `.vscode` folder.
You can find more on these options in the VSCode [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/php).

Comment: That worked. I added this to the settings-Section in my workspace save file (projectname.code-workspace).

Answer (score 8):

As you can see on https://github.com/bmewburn/vscode-intelephense/milestone/26: they are actively working on adding support for PHP8. Any further questions should be posted in their issue tracker

---

Best credible source, posted on Dec 09 on https://github.com/bmewburn/vscode-intelephense/issues/1525#issuecomment-742115154:

> It's being actively worked on. Should be out soon.

Comment: I've noticed strange thing - even though current marketplace version of intelephense is 1.8, my vscode still shows only 1.5.4, I had to uninstall it and install it again to get the latest extension version. However even if I set `8.1.2` for both User & Workspace "Intelephense › Environment: PHP Version" - named arguments are still red as errors.

Answer (score 3):

[This answer solved my problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72098512), even tho i don't use a mac.

I still had an old php version linked in my VSCode settings of my WSL integration (`settings.json`). Removing that line, fixed the errors.