# Laravel 9 + PHP 8.0.8 in VSCode shows syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR)

Tags: laravel, php-8

Why is my freshly created laravel 9 project on PHP 8.0.8 showing an error by Visual Studio Code ?

VSCode shows this as an error :

```
return Limit::perMinute(60)->by($request->user()?->id ?: $request->ip());
```

[image]

Comment: try installing any Laravel coding assist plugins they usually help

Comment: Weird, what i notice is that you have **doble suggestion**, maybe you are using two extensions for php and that is bothering you? I recommend you to use PHP Inteliphense only -> https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bmewburn.vscode-intelephense-client

Comment: In any case, you are able to use your app? is that "wrong sentence" stopping you to use the app? or it is working correctly?

Comment: Have you checked that VSCode knows you're using PHP 8.0? The [nullsafe operator](https://www.php.net/releases/8.0/en.php#nullsafe-operator) is new in that release, so if VSCode thinks you're using an older version, it would show that error.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: If you figured out the problem, don't forget to [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) so that it can be useful to other readers in future :)

Comment: I found out the reason why VSCode is showing an error - VSCode is detecting the default version of PHP on my macOS, PHP 7.1.33 and not my 8.0.8 installation - I am still looking for the solution - https://serverfault.com/q/1100013/39540

Answer (score 2):

If you're using MAMP on a macOS which has PHP pre-installed like PHP 7.1.33 on macOS Mojave then change in Visual Studio Code settings, PHP > Validate: Executable Path - edit in settings.json :

```
"php.validate.executablePath": ""
or
"php.validate.executablePath": "/usr/bin/php"
to 
"php.validate.executablePath": "/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php8.0.8/bin/php"
```

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/php

Comment: I've done this and VSCode still doesn't know about PHP 8 functions such as str_starts_with().